# Flutter Compliler Error - Java Files Import

Tags: java, flutter, wifi

guys, if you can help me with this problem, i appreciate it.

I'm trying to use a plugin in flutter made in java, I put the 2 java files (WifiDelegate.java and WifiPlugin.java) in the app/src/main/java/com/ly/wifi folder and their packages are com.ly.wifi.

Follows the dart file where I invoke the created methods. In "MethodChannel" I pass the path of the plugin.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

enum WifiState { error, success, already }

class Wifi {//io.flutter.plugins
    static const MethodChannel _channel = const MethodChannel('plugins.ly.com/wifi');

    static Future<String> get ssid async {
        return await _channel.invokeMethod('ssid');
    }

    static Future<int> get level async {
        return await _channel.invokeMethod('level');
    }

    static Future<String> get ip async {
        return await _channel.invokeMethod('ip');
    }

    static Future<List<WifiResult>> list(String key) async {
        end Map<String, dynamic> params = {
            'key': key,
        };
        var results = await _channel.invokeMethod('list', params);
        List<WifiResult> resultList = [];
        for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            resultList.add(WifiResult(results[i]['ssid'], results[i]['level']));
        }
        return resultList;
    }

    static Future<WifiState> connection(String ssid, String password) async {
        end Map<String, dynamic> params = {
            'ssid': ssid,
            'password': password,
        };
        int state = await _channel.invokeMethod('connection', params);

        switch (state) {
            case 0:
                return WifiState.error;
            case 1:
                return WifiState.success;
            case 2:
                return WifiState.already;
            default:
                return WifiState.error;
        }
   }
}

class WifiResult {
    String ssid;
    int level;

    WifiResult(this.ssid, this.level);
}
```

When I run my app, the following errors appear, and when I try to use --no-shrink or --stacktrace they are not found:

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
 Learn how to solve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
 Program type already present: com.ly.wifi.WifiDelegate$NetworkChangeReceiver
                                                                    
>* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug 
option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
                                                                    
> BUILD FAILED in 6s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done 7.3s
>* The shrinker may have failed to optimize the Java bytecode.
To disable the shrinker, pass the `--no-shrink` flag to this command.
To learn more, see: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code
```

Comment: Looks you are using Gradle, could you list the dependencies? Seems like you might need to exclude one of them.

Look at this:

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes